# Spark loosing data from dataframe after saving

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I experienced some weird behaviour with a spark dataframe. It is Spark Version version 2.4.0 (before i had thought 2.6 thus edited)

UPDATE:

I read in data from a "csv"-type file in spark, i run a querie for a specific dataset and it is found.
Then I save that dataframe to parquet and some data is lost. But not all.

here my code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
# in readschema I provide a StructType object with the right schema
import readschema as rs

os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = "UTF-8"
READ_ENCODING = "iso-8859-1"



delim = "\t"
null_value = ""
schema = rs.FILE
file = "hdfs://path/to/file"

df = spark.read.schema(schema) \
            .options(header="TRUE") \
            .option("encoding", READ_ENCODING) \
            .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
            .option("delimiter", delim) \
            .option("nullValue", null_value) \
            .csv(file)
df.show()
# looks good, no problems in schema visible 
# (otherwise dropmalformed option would drop alot, i guess)
```

If I run a df.show, everything looks good. Then i run the querie and save that dataframe, read it again and get puzzled..

```py
# i mask the actual data
# if there is inconsistency in key, value probably due to
# masking, i hope :)

>>> def execute_spark_sql(df, query, view_name="TB_TEMP"):
...     df.createOrReplaceTempView(view_name)
...     return spark.sql(query)
>>> execute_spark_sql(df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key'").show()
+--------------+---------+
|       cell_id|cell_name|
+--------------+---------+
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxx| key     |
+--------------+---------+
>>> df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet") \
...     .option("header", "true").save("/path/to/debug/df")
>>> new_df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/debug/df")
>>> new_df.show()
# output of show() looks good, there is sufficient data to not get suspicious


>>> execute_spark_sql(new_df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key'").show()
+-------+---------+
|cell_id|cell_name|
+-------+---------+
+-------+---------+

# but another key is found:

>>> execute_spark_sql(new_df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key2'").show()
+--------------+---------+
|       cell_id|cell_name|
+--------------+---------+
|zzzzzzzzzzzz  |  key2   |
+--------------+---------+

>>> execute_spark_sql(df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key2'").show()
+--------------+---------+
|       cell_id|cell_name|
+--------------+---------+
|zzzzzzzzzzzz  |  key2   |
+--------------+---------+
```

So my problem that i thought happens after joining the data (as written in the original text below) is actually a data loss, when saving the data frame.

These data somehow are random for me, but not for the computer, as it is the same keys that get lost.
I also loose rows when running a df.distinct() but not do i loose duplicate entries but all entries of specific keys.

It actually looses the same keys:

```py
>>> dist_df = df.distinct()
>>> dist_df.show()
# here the output again looks unsuspicious

>>> execute_spark_sql(dist_df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key2'").show()
+--------------+---------+
|       cell_id|cell_name|
+--------------+---------+
|zzzzzzzzzzz   |  key2   |
+--------------+---------+

>>> execute_spark_sql(dist_df, "Select cell_id, cell_name from TB_TEMP where cell_name='key'").show()
+-------+---------+
|cell_id|cell_name|
+-------+---------+
+-------+---------+
```

So there is a link, but i don't really get it. Does spark run a distinct on the dataframe before saving in parquet (actually i tested saving to csv, also i loose the data here).

Thanks and BR teaVeloper

---

OLD VERSION (for completeness):

So i am reading about 12 csv Files and join them to one dataframe. In the first CSV file that i read in, there is some particular data in column A with Key-Value 'key'
e.g.

Select key, A from dataframe where key=key;
will return

```
| key | A      |
|-----|---     |
|"key" | value |
```

after that i will join all other CSV files on the key columns.

It works great and after each join i output the querie and it is perfectly fine. I do some other transformations with my data frame, i do some window function and joins on another key as well.
Still always when i querie, this will return the right value.

Then i save my dataframe into a parquet file, just before that i output my querie, its fine. But in my parquet file, this specific querie results in

```
| key | A      |
|-----|---     |
|"key" | null  |
```

I don't loose all data, just some - not really randomly, as in every computation its always the same key that gets los, but other keys in the same file don't have this behaviour. I couldn't properly see if there is a relationship between lost keys and which csv files they are and which not.

Also what i noticed is, that with particular files, especially the first one, that holds the key and value pair that i am loosing, when i run dataframe.distinct() i will loose the same or even more data.

I hope my description is clear?

here some code

```py
# i changed some domain specific parts of the code, i hope i didn't break it through this 
# process

def attributes(left_dataframe, right_dataframe):
    left_columns = left_dataframe.columns
    right_columns = right_dataframe.columns
    common_attributes = list(frozenset(left_columns).intersection(right_columns))
    right_attributes = list(set(right_columns) - set(common_attributes))
    left_attributes = list(set(left_columns) - set(common_attributes))
    return {"intersect": common_attributes, "right": right_attributes, "left": left_attributes}

def join_querie_builder(left, right, left_name, right_name):
    atts = attributes(left, right)
    quer = "SELECT left.key as key "
    for att in atts["intersect"]:
        if att not in ["key"]:
            quer = quer + ", CASE WHEN left." + att + " is NULL then right." + \
                   att + " else left." + att + " END as " + att
    for att in atts["right"]:
        quer = quer + ", right." + att
    for att in atts["left"]:
        if att not in {"key"}:
            quer = quer + ", left." + att
    quer = quer + " FROM " + left_name + " as left LEFT JOIN " + \
                           right_name + " AS right ON left.key = right.key"
    return quer

# schemaswitcher is imported from a seperate code file (as rs for read_schema ), which holds
# all proper schema definitions for each of the files
READ_ENCODING = "iso-8859-1"

for id, file in enumerate(files):
    filename = file.split('/')[-1].split(".")[0]
    schema = schemaSwitcher.get(filename, rs.DEFAULT)
    if file.endswith(".gz"):
        log_info("working on " + file + " ...")
        if file.endswith("txt.gz"):
            delim = "\t"
            null_value = ""
        else:
            delim = ";"
            null_value = " "

        df = spark.read.schema(schema) \
            .options(header="TRUE") \
            .option("encoding", READ_ENCODING) \
            .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
            .option("delimiter", delim) \
            .option("nullValue", null_value) \
            .csv(file)
        # do some transformations
        df_switcher_detail[filename] = df

def join_to_left(left_df, switcher, right_name):
    left_t_name = "TB_RAN"
    right_t_name = "T_FILE"
    log_info("joining " + name)
    temp = switcher[right_name]
    left_df.createOrReplaceTempView(left_t_name)
    temp.createOrReplaceTempView(right_t_name)
    sparkQuery = join_querie_builder(left_df, temp, left_t_name, right_t_name)
    return spark.sql(sparkQuery)

for name in listData:
    ran_detail = join_to_left(ran_detail, df_switcher_detail, name)

# some more transformations happen, but they don't break
# it will be to verbose i guess to write all
# but there is also window functions that are used to create sub_ids for non-unique rows
# regarding the key (in all columns they are unique)

# execute_spark_sql is just a wrapper around spark.sql, whith creating a temp view, etc. 
# returning a new dataframe

execute_spark_sql(ran_detail, "Select A, B, C, D, key from TB_TEMP where key='key'").show()
# this executions shows the values properly
ran_detail.write.repartition(4).mode("overwrite").format("parquet")
         .option("header", "true").save("hdfs://path/to/file/")
```

the file is properly saved and contains of most of the data, but if i go for instance into pyspark console, read that file and run the querie i just did before saving, i will get the row with that key and NULL inside the column A that is important for me.

I am really puzzled about that behaviour.

Thanks and BR
teaVeloper

Comment: Hi, your code is extremely complex. It would be great if you could reduce it to the minimal code that reproduces the problem. It will help us see what's wrong, and in the process, it might help you see it as well ;)

Comment: thanks, i will try my best. It is not an easy task i notice right now while attempting.. :)
I will edit my question once i have the code ready